# Accessing another object field variables performance cost (locality of reference)

Tags: java, performance, optimization, jvm, localityofreference

Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358679/accessing-local-field-vs-object-field-is-doc-wrong) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12359079/6312119) I know that accessing fields will cost some performance in AOT compilers (thanks to JVM I can forget about it)

Now please guide me about this scenario:

```
public class Foo
{
    Object fooObject;
}

public class Bar
{
    Foo foo;
    Object fooObjectCopy = foo.fooObject; // fooObject replica of object foo (not a clone)
    void barMethod1()
    {
        doSomething (fooObjectCopy);
    }
    void barMethod2()
    {
        doSomething (foo.fooObject);
    }
}
```

Both `barMethod1()` and `barMethod2()` do the same thing. The question is which one does better (in terms of performance) if:

1. `fooObject` is a primitive type
2. `fooObject` is an object instance

P.S. Please consider both accessing cost and cache miss.

Comment: Feel free to edit my question to make it more clarified.

Comment: what have you tried so far? microbenchmarks? looked at the generated assembly? or the bytecodes at least?

Comment: I will do a micro benchmark but because the code piece is small I think no cache miss is expected. This should be done in a large piece of code

Comment: Result is different every time I run. Sometimes first one takes longer sometimes second one. Looped for 10000000000L times